# How to get fname and lname in a custom Model after Extending it from django's User Model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have `User` model class which is in `accounts.models`. I have then created an `Employee` class in `hr.models` and I have added `user` as a `ForeignKeyField`. How do I make it possible to implement a method in  `Employee` class to view both first and last name?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    provider = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='rel_doc')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s (%s)" % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.username)
```

In `hr.models`:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='users',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Sex)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'hr.Company',
        verbose_name='Company',
        related_name='companies',
        null=True, blank=True,
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key to User, you can simply follow it with dot notation:

```
print(self.user.firstname, self.user.lastname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following methods to the Employee class

```
def get_first_name(self):
    return self.user.first_name

def last_name(self):
    return self.user.last_name

def get_full_name(self):
    return self.user.get_full_name()
```

refer this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_full_name) for more details

Answer (score 0):

In serializers.py I imported:
`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`
then defined  `user = UserSerializer()` within the `EmployeeSerializer` class

`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        # fields = ['id', 'user', 'dob', 'gender', 'hr_number', 'company', 'marital_status', 'identification_type',
        #             'tax_id_number','joining_date', 'designation', 'department']
        fields = '__all__'
```

After that in  the views I just define:

```
class ListEmployees(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    List all employees.
    """
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```